# SQL Server integrated security without SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, security, web-config, integrated-security

I am using integrated security in an ASP.net application, the IIS and SQL Server are both hosted on the same server machine running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Is it possible to allow users to access the application from across the network AND logged in users but not let them access the database directly or via SQL Server Management Studio?

I am trying to safeguard the database access because my application is going to be deployed on the client's server at client's premises.

Here is my connection string that i am currently using

```
<add connectionString="Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=DB89akwA;Integrated Security=true" name="LocalSqlServer" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add connectionString="Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=DB89akwA;Integrated Security=true" name="MainAppConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

These are the two connection strings i am currently using, one is for ASP.net Authentication and second is used by my application. These both strings are the same and of the same database.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If a user has access to a SQL Server database, he (or she) has access to it no matter what tools they use. If they get access to the actual data tables so they can use your application, then they can also connect to the same database using MS-Access or Excel and grab (and possibly even manipulate) data

Comment: seperate ASP.NET connection string (KEEP IT TO integrated security) while for SQL Server Connection String (Authenticate using Username and password).... As Already mentioned in my answer. Thanks

Comment: Several ways: (1) don't use SQL Server integrated security, so your users don't have direct access; use an "application" user for your ASP.NET app that has the necessary permissions on SQL Server; this keeps out "casual" hackers, but any sysadmin can see your SQL connection string including user/pwd in web.config. Also: use permissions on the database - the "normal" user can only change "normal" tables (no system/lookup tables); use database constraints and referential integrity (foreign keys) to prevent invalid data

Comment: (2) if you're **really** paranoid about security, architect your solution so **any** user can only access your data using stored procedures; in that case, any user on the database only needs permission to execute stored procedures - he has **no permission** directly on the tables, so he cannot do anything to those tables. This requires massive re-architecting, however, if you didn't do it like that from the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to 'secure' a database running on client's premises. The client's staff can get the password from the ASP.Net connection string. A domain administrator can **always** gain access to the database (there is an actual MSDN article describing the process: [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx)).

If you want to hide the Intelectual Property you feel your database has, then your only solution is to not deploy the database on the client premise (use a hosted database like SQL Azure for instance).

If you simply want to prevent the client from interfering with the database you can stipulate so in the contract. Auditing and detecting interference **is** possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, The product is a customized ERP system, more than intellectual property, i am worried about mis-handling of the data and unauthorized access. At Client's organization, it is common for people to share passwords. i know i can explain them not to do and other contractual clauses, but just wanted to be more productive by restricting that access by a separate User Credential, not used by others in the staff. :(

Comment: You can certainly elevate the bar. You know, locks don't keep thieves out, they keep people honest. Look into [Logon triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx), you can write a trigger that simply refuses access from SSMS see [this example](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/logon-triggers/). And certainly install [Audit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx) and advertise its presence, this will detter most unauthorised access attempts.

Comment: yes i guess i agree with you, since @Athar suggested an alternative but with the current setup that i have, its not gonna work. So i mark your answer since it directly reply to my query and Athar being very helpful as well.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, that is completely possible. A Person logged in to ASP.NET using integrated security can not log in to SQL Server with the same credentials. Both are completely disconnected. It is only possible if the SQL Server has been set to allow them access.

My Piece of advice would be to create SQL Login and users, and only give them access to SQL Server. In your application, when you create the Connection String, do not set integrated security to true, and just let the user enter his Sql username and password to access the database.

Comment: If that person's credentials are used to log into SQL Server - how can you prevent them from accessing SQL Server with their credentials (which obviously allow them to connect to SQL Server) using e.g. MS-Access?

Comment: thats what i said, IT is only possible if the SQL Server has been set to allow them access. read my comment carefully

Comment: But that's **exactly** what the OP is saying, no? He's using *integrated security* (implying the users running his app can also connect to SQL Server using their Windows identity) - and if he really does, there's **no way** to prevent those users from using MS-Access to connect to SQL Server ...

Comment: he is using integrated security through ASP.NET Configuration to connect to the site. Not to the sql server! Thats what i understood.

Comment: Well, the title says *SQL Server integrated security* .... so that kinda implies he's using integrated security on the SQL Server part, too - don't you agree?

Comment: @AtharAnis Thanks Athar, but as marc_s said, i am asking about SQL Server Integrated security. but lets say according to your answer, it made me think in a positive alternative, can i run SQL Server with credentials i.e. username and passwords and ASP.Net in integrated security mode? do i have to migrate SQL Server to another machine? any help or links are appreciated.

Comment: No, you do not need to migrate SQL to another machine @Thr3e , you can keep both on the same machine. And Its a good practice to have the SQL seperated from ASP.NET to boost up security. And specially in environments like your client's environment, this approach is unavoidable. one MUST adopt this approach to add another layer of security.

Comment: @AtharAnis Can you suggest any helpful links for further info? thanks